# Calculated column increase date column by one day

Tags: calculated-column, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I want to create acalculated column that takes a date field and sets the value to the date, increased by one day. How can this be done?

For ex:

If date field value: `20/10/2015`
calculated result will be: `21/10/2015`

Suggest some formula to use.

Comment: =[Date]+1. However it does not update automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Date columns are essentially numbers starting at 30/12/1899

So besides adding one day, you have to display it as a date again (when using it in a Calculated Column datatype=Text)

```
=TEXT( [Due Date]+1 , "dd/mm/yyyy" )
```

Or set the datatype of the Calculated Column to Date

```
=[Due Date]+1
```

Adding one day correctly counts the new date

```
=TEXT(DATE(2015,12,31+1),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

outputs january 1st 2016

More Date functions: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List